UnknownPackageError: Could not find the package
I try fix a little program for smoker, i use VBC and i can't solve this problem.
when I try to run it I get a message in the terminal:
Processing myenv (platform: espressif32; board: esp32doit-devkit-v1; framework: arduino)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------Library Manager: Installing br3ttb/Arduino-PID-Library @ ^1.2.1
UnknownPackageError: Could not find the package with 'br3ttb/Arduino-PID-Library @ ^1.2.1' requirements for your system 'windows_amd64'

this id info from output:

Resolving myenv dependencies...
Library Manager: Installing br3ttb/Arduino-PID-Library @ ^1.2.1
UnknownPackageError: Could not find the package with 'br3ttb/Arduino-PID-Library @ ^1.2.1' requirements for your system 'windows_amd64'

Earlier same problem occured with ESPAsyncWebServer

Read the documentation about Package Management. If you are using micropython or Installing Libraries if you are using Arduino IDE.

Problem is, libraries are installed, and it is shown in libdeps.

Ok, obviously the error message doesn't think so. You need to explain in more detail what is your IDE environment, how do you install the library or how you setup the libdeps. We are not hear trying to guess what you are trying to do if you can't tell us.
